# NetBeans suporta Django?

Tags: python, django, netbeans

Instalei o [NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/PythonInstall) e os [plugins para python](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/56795?show=true).

Deu tudo certo, mas achei  o que não ocorreu.que esse plugin sozinho já daria suporte a Django.

[Vi neste blog](https://%C2%ADchevitarese.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/django-netbeans-ide-for-python/) o autor dizendo que gostou do NetBeans também para Django, porém o link que ele dá está quebrado (a postagem é de 2009, a versão era outra, isso explica).

A única coisa que consegui encontrar de Django para NetBeans foi [este projeto](https://code.google.com/p/netbeans-django/), mas parece ser apenas um projeto abandonado, sem qualquer suporte, e não tem nenhuma referência sobre como utilizá-lo.

De fato, NetBeans suporta Django? Se sim, alguém pode me ajudar em como proceder?

Comment: Por que não usar Pycharm? Há a versão community que é muito boa. ALém do fato de ter sido desenvolvida pela Jetbrains.

Comment: Sobre Pycharm, a versão community não suporta Django, só Python. A versão Professional suporta Django, em contrapartida é necessário comprar uma licença. Mas é uma boa opção, já testei e até achei legal, embora fraco, mas suficiente para trabalhar. Eu já desisti do NetBeans e na verdade resolvi dar um tempo no Django/python, mas deixo a pergunta para caso surja uma boa resposta para ajudar outro no futuro. Mas obrigado pela dica que realmente é útil.

Comment: netbeans-django não é um projeto ativo. Além do mais, netbeans nunca suportou Python nativamente. Também, embora Django não seja um recurso gratuito Pycharm ainda vale MUITO usar a IDE. O suporte a Python, codeintelligence, code scan/code browser, virtual enviroments etc.. é excelente e duvido muito que você precisa mais que isso para trabalhar. Afinal, isso é Python!

Comment: Estou começando a desenvolver em Python com o Django. Antes eu utilizava o Netbeans para desenvolvimento Java - PHP. Mas gostei muito do PyCharm como IDE para o desenvolvimento de aplicações python. Seria uma boa dar uma olhada. Não sei se ajudei! Mas garanto que essa foi a minha real intenção! Abraços!

Answer (score 3):

Peço desculpas antecipadas - não vou responder a sua pergunta. Mas vou colocar umas perguntas de volta:

Porquê você precisa de uma  "IDE para Django"? Quem usa Python a mais tempo, emg eral não usa uma IDE nem para a linguagem - em Python, as coisas são mais concisas e uma IDE especial para cada coisinha que você vai fazer  não é algo tão necessário.

Se em vez de ficar procurando plug-ins para IDE, para depois aprender como funciona o NEtBeans, como funciona o Netbeans com Python e como funciona o NetBeans com Python com Django, você for na docuemntação do Python 
(http://python.org, http://wiki.python.org.br ) e na documentação do Django 
(https://www.djangoproject.com/,  e tem um tutorial em português em https://web.archive.org/web/20140711105221/http://docs.djangobrasil.org/intro/tutorial01.html ) - vai poder aprender a parte que interessa de verdade, e não ficar dependendo de ferramentas específicas.

Django, como outros frameworks mais complexos em outras linguagens, depende de um conjunto não tão pequeno de arquivos para que o projeto possa existir. Mas ao contrário de frameworks em Java por exemplo, a criação desses arquivos básicos não depende deles serem criados por uma IDE específica: o próprio framework tem comandos para criar novos projetos, e inicializarem os arquivos de configuração, pastas de views e etc...

Ou você já imaginou um escritor precisando de uma "caneta da Bic" para escrever, senão não escreve?

Comment: Olá amigo, não precisa pedir desculpas, eu que agradeço pela resposta.
Preciso de uma IDE para django pois desejo: IntelliSense (o mais importante), corretor de erros, comandos que automatizem tarefas, dentre outras coisas.
Amigo tenho visto que sua visão é muito comum no mundo python, infelizmente. Agradeço mesmo por tentar me ajudar, mas quem já trabalhou em projeto de porte médio a grande sabe que uma boa IDE é indispensável à produtividade e até aprendizado.
Se vou cortar uma árvore, para que usar um facão se existe a motosserra?
Ainda assim agradeço por querer ajudar.
Ps:Venho de Asp.Net.

Comment: Ok - e por que uma IDE que suporte apenas Python com o "intelisense" não te ajuda? Uma vez você tendo o ambiente com o Django configurado, as APIs do mesmo são apenas mais módulos e classes que a IDE deveria achar normalmente.

Comment: Eu poderia exemplificar três pontos que imagino, mas não únicos: suporte à linguagem de templates, atalhos para rodar comandos no Manage.py (ex. migrate e syncdb) e a compreensão de configurações no settings.py (que ajudariam no intellisense, refatoramento de código, etc).

Comment: Utilizar uma IDE se resume em uma palavra: Produtividade. Se por seguir uma linha extremista, que usemos o vim/emacs e fiquemos 100% na linha de comando :)

Comment: vim/emacs tem plug-ins de produtividade que podem deixar muita ide gráfica no chinelo.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme [o link que você postou](http://wiki.netbeans.org/PythonInstall), o Netbeans não suporta oficialmente o Python, isto é, o suporte a essa linguagem é mantido pela comunidade.

> This project is a community driven effort. Oracle does not actively participate in or directly support this effort.

Também não encontrei nada relacionado a Django para trabalhar com Netbeans, por outro lado você pode utilizar o [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) juntamente com o [Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/python-vs.aspx), que suporta o Django.

[image: Projeto Django no Visual Studio]

<sup><sup>Na minha opnião o Visual Studio é muito mais IDE que o Netbeans :)</sup></sup>